# Problem with ord () and string

Tags: delphi, console-application, delphi-xe

i having this problem, if i have:

mychr = ' ';

where the 'space' in mychr equival to #255 (typed manually ALT+255), and i write:

myord = ord (mychr)

to myord return value 160 and not 255. Of course, same problem is too with charater ALT+254 etc.
As i can solve this problem? I have tested on delphi xe in console mode.

Note: if i use:

mychar = #255;

then function ord() return value correctly.

Answer (score 9):

I think the problem is that the Windows Alt+Num shortcuts insert characters according to the local codepage, whereas a modern Delphi use Unicode characters, and these differ (unless the value is less than or equal to 127, I think). The solution is to enter the values `#255` explicitly in code. In addition, it is a *very bad habit* to include 'invisible' special characters in code, because you cannot tell what character it is without copying in to an external tool! In addition, you will have to trust the text encoding of the `.pas` file. It is *much* better to use constants like `#255`. Even better, do

```
const
  MY_PRECIOUS_VALUE = #255;
```

and use this constant every time you need it.

**Update**

According to the English Wikipedia article on [Alt code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Alt_keycodes):

> If the number typed has a leading 0
>   (zero), the character set used is the
>   Windows code page that matches the
>   current input locale. For most systems
>   using the Latin alphabet, this is
>   Windows-1252. For a complete list, see
>   code page. If the number does not have
>   a leading 0 (zero), DOS compatibility
>   is invoked. The character set used is
>   the DOS code page for the current
>   input locale. For systems using
>   English, this is code page 437. For
>   most other systems using the Latin
>   alphabet, this is code page 850. For a
>   complete list, see code page.

So, if you really, really want to continue entering Alt keycodes, you'd better type Alt and `0255` with the leading zero.

Comment: @Andriy M: You are totally right. Of course, I was thinking about *typing* `Alt+0225` with the leading zero.

Answer (score 3):

If you type `ALT+255`, DOS codepage is used; for 437 and 850 DOS codepages (one of which you probably use) #255 is NBSP (non-breaking space). In Unicode, NBSP is $A0 (160). That explains why you obtain Ord 160.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK console mode use the OEM Ansi char set. And under Delphi XE, you're not in the Ansi world, but in the UCS-2 / Unicode world.

```
var MyChar: char;
    MyWideChar: WideChar; 
    MyAnsiChar: AnsiChar;
begin
  MyChar := #255;
  MyWideChar := #255;
  MyAnsiChar := #255;
```

The first two variables are the same, i.e. a character with Unicode code 255 = $00FF, since in Delphi XE, `char = WideChar`. For the first Unicode Page, see [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF).

But `MyAnsiChar` is what will be displayed on the console, after conversion from the current code page into the OEM console code page.

In the Unicode chart, this $00FF is a minuscule y with trema:

```
U+00FF ÿ Latin Small Letter Y with diaeresis
```

Under the console, you'll use the [OEM char set, i.e. Code Page 347](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). So in your case $FF is NOT a character, but a special code

```
FF  NBSP  Non Breaking SPace
```

which is converted into U+00A0 when converted back to Unicode:

```
U+00A0 NBSP  Non Breaking SPace
```

It is very likely that you are in a [Windows-1252 code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), so normally the Delphi XE AnsiString will map #255 into a minuscule y with trema:

```
FF ÿ Latin Small Letter Y with diaeresis
```

You can use low-level e.g. [CharToOemBuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) windows functions to perform the conversion to or from OEM, or use an OEM AnsiString type:

```
type
  TOemString = AnsiString(437);
```

In all cases, the console is not the best way of entering accentuated text under modern Windows, and Unicode Delphi XE.

Using `InputQuery` function e.g. should be safer, since it will return an Unicode `string` variable. ;)

Comment: Hello i try to explain better mine problem. For example i have:

    x := '';
    for i := 0 to 255 do x := x + chr (i);

    for i := 0 to 255 do writeln (ord (x [i]));

Simply i want to do that ord (x [i]) in second cycle, return me all value from 0 to 255 exactely as i setted with chr in first cycle.
I have understood that problem is about set of character, but i ask as i can solve it.
I need solve it, for to have possibility to write correctly a algoritm that work with file and strings reading one for time all single character.
Thanks again for help.